# c++ Passing templated unique_ptr by value

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a derived class of which I want to create a unique_ptr and pass it to a function.
I can do this as follows:

```
#include <memory>

struct Base{};

struct Derived : public Base
{};

void foo(std::unique_ptr<Base> sink)
{    
}

int main(){
    foo(std::make_unique<Derived>());    

    return 0;
}
```

But when I want to do this with Derived being templated this no longer compiles:

```
#include <memory>

struct Dummy
{};

template<class D>
struct Base{};

template<class D>
struct Derived : public Base<D>
{};

template<class D>
void foo(std::unique_ptr<Base<D>> sink)
{    
}

int main(){
    foo(std::make_unique<Derived<Dummy>>()); //does not compile    
    //foo(std::unique_ptr<Base<Dummy>>(new Derived<Dummy>())); // compiles

    return 0;
}
```

I can work around it by defining a Base unique ptr and initializing it with a derived bare pointer.

```
foo(std::unique_ptr<Base<Dummy>>(new Derived<Dummy>()));
```

However that seems a bit wrong.

Is there a reason I am missing why this does not compile?
Also are there other ways I am missing how I can use the templated class and don't need to use bare pointers?

compile [mcve1](https://godbolt.org/z/_BLeOg)
compile [mcve2](https://godbolt.org/z/dl3KBN)

Comment: Please include your mcve's in the question.

Comment: @LogicStuff You need to uncomment the failing line in the second one.

Comment: `unique_ptr` cannot be passed by value as that would invoke a non-existent copy constructor. You could move the pointer, but it's unlikely you want to function to take ownership. You could instead use the `get` method to pass a pointer to the data along. Using smart pointers requires more than just "make all the things smart pointers." You need to consider ownership and transferring that ownership.

Comment: @sweenish exact wording could maybe be better but as you can see I'm not trying to invoke the copy constructor. I am creating the unique ptr in place and the function gets ownership.

Comment: I did see that. I was more just clarifying based on the wording in case someone else saw this question and assumed that actual copy by value is allowed for `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler, in this case, is just not able to deduce the type. You can help it by passing the type:

```
foo<Dummy>(std::make_unique<Derived<Dummy>>());
```

But if you declare `foo` like this:

```
template <template<class, class> class X, class Y, class Z>
void foo(X<Y,Z> sink) {}
```

or like this:

```
template<class D, class S>
void foo(std::unique_ptr<D, S> sink){}
```

It will work for both:

```
foo(std::make_unique<Derived<Dummy>>());
foo(std::unique_ptr<Base<Dummy>>(new Derived<Dummy>()));
```